# How to show the effect that an item in a ListView overlaps to the next item position under?

Tags: android, android-listview

So I have a ListView. Each item in the ListView represents 1 hour (Day view for a calendar). What if something, basically an event is, say 1 hour and 30 minutes. I need to be able to extend it past that one bracket/item without making it look separated, which is what the divider line in ListView is doing, which is not what I want. Problem is I do not want to nullify the divider value as I need the dividers there. Any ideas on how to accomplish this will be much appreciated!

Comment: Have You tried negative dividerHeight or items paddings? (first definitely provides overlapping, but not sure about all versions)

Comment: Hmm, I did not even know the divider itself had any padding. But I did not think of the negative divider height. Thanks for that hint. I'll give it a try

Comment: Just checked one of my projects, smth like android:dividerHeight="-10.0dp" did the trick for me there and provided nice looking overlapping in the list. But it get applied for every item, so not sure if it's that You're looking for.

Comment: @sandrstar Damn, no thats not what I'm looking for. It was close though. I appreciate you trying. I did have a random idea. Not sure if it'll work. I was thinking of putting the `ListView` in a `RelativeLayout`. Then dynamically add Views to the RelativeLayout with margins matching where everything is. Since the size of each item is a fixed hight, that might work.

Comment: Tried what you told me, they both don't work. Setting the `dividerHeight` to a negative number is not what I am looking for and the items do not have any padding or margins :/ first thing I tried.